# Javafx error not working button

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I have created small application. It's an `AlertBox` using `JavaFX` in `Netbeans`. My problem is that after showing the `AlertBox` when click on `OK` -button my `AlertBox` is not closing.

code is as follows.

newfxmain,java page code is as follows

```
public class NewFXMain extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Button b1;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage MainEvent)  {
       window=MainEvent;
       window.setTitle("hello");
       b1=new Button("click");
       b1.setOnAction(e -> AlertBox.display("hello", "welcome"));

       StackPane stk= new StackPane();
       stk.getChildren().add(b1);
       Scene sc= new Scene(stk,300,300);
       window.setScene(sc);
       window.show();                      
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Class for `AlertBox`

```
public class AlertBox {
     public static void display(String title, String message) {
         Stage window= new Stage();
         window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
         window.setTitle(title);
         window.setMaxWidth(250);
         Label label1=new Label("hello");
         Button b1= new Button("close");
         b1.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
         VBox vb=new VBox(20);
         vb.getChildren().addAll(label1,b1);
         vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
         Scene sc= new Scene(vb);

         window.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: `showAndWait()` blocks the dispatch and execution of events, so the `window.close()` does not get called until the window is already closed... Try `show()` instead...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto You're wrong: From [the javadoc:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--) *Shows this stage and waits for it to be hidden (closed) before returning to the caller. [...]  A `Stage` is hidden (closed) by one of the following means: \* the application calls the Window.hide() or close() method on this stage [...]*

Comment: BTW This will not show a `OK` button. No button with the text `OK` is created in your code. Furthermore you never set the scene for the window created in the `display` method, so not even a button with some other text will be shown...

Comment: @fabian Left out the most important aspect: "This method temporarily blocks processing of the current event, and starts a nested event loop to handle other events."

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Yes it blocks the event handler after showing the new stage and then enters a nested event loop that handles events and runs until the new window gets closed. If the OP would attach the scene to the window this would cause the button's event handler to call `window.close()` to be executed on a button click thereby exiting the nested event loop.

Comment: so what is answer dear members?

Comment: @fabian I have mentioned display options in my code (both classes)

Comment: As @fabian has mentioned, add `window.setScene(sc);` to the `AlertBox` class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add vb to the scene.
2. Use show instead of showAndWait

this works fine.

```
public class NewFXMain extends Application {
        Stage window;
        Button b1;
        @Override
        public void start(Stage MainEvent)  {
           window=MainEvent;
           window.setTitle("hello");
           b1=new Button("click");
           b1.setOnAction(e -> AlertBox.display("hello", "welcome"));

           StackPane stk= new StackPane();
           stk.getChildren().add(b1);
           Scene sc= new Scene(stk,300,300);
           window.setScene(sc);
           window.show();                      
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
       static  public class AlertBox {
         public  static void display(String title, String message) {
             Stage window= new Stage();
             window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
             window.setTitle(title);
             window.setMaxWidth(250);
             Label label1=new Label("hello");
             Button b1= new Button("close");
             b1.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
             VBox vb=new VBox();
             vb.getChildren().addAll(label1,b1);
             vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

             Scene sc= new Scene(vb,300,300);

             window.setScene(sc);

             window.show();
        }
    }
    }
```